# I want to import a csv file that has comma in the data powershell

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am new to Powershell and want to import a csv file that has comma in one of the data field like in address. The comma is coming in single quotes but the Import-csv is considering that comma as a delimiter and splitting the data

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameter –Delimiter to the Import-CSV command
**Import-CSV "C:\temp\test.csv" –Delimiter “;”**